# when i executed command- bundle exec rake db:create,I am getting an error rake aborted! NotImplementedError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

when i executed command-`bundle exec rake db:create`,I am getting an error

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(in C:/Users/Misha/Documents/readers_door)
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:86: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
rake aborted!
NotImplementedError
```

and when execute `bundle exec rake`,i get an error-

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(in C:/Users/Misha/Documents/readers_door)
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:9: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils.rb:86: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
C:/Users/Misha/Documents/readers_door/db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rake db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a database, you should instead alter C:/Users/Misha/Documents/readers_door/config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that will be loaded.
```

Comment: working with ror on windows may not help in finding answers sometimes..

Answer (score 0):

Although the Rails 4 gem allows the 0.8.7 version of rake, I don't think it actually works.  Try upgrading your rake with: `bundle update rake`  Then re-run your commands, that should work.